# Перегружаемый метод и класс Потоков

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Господа, возникла небольшая синтаксическая трудность. Есть 2 перегружаемых метода

```
public void A() { }
public void A(object o) { }
```

Как известно, объект класса Thread принимает сигнатуру любого из этих методов. Однако как именно указать, какой метод я пытаюсь передать в объект класса Thread. Ведь при указании метода используется только его имя без скобок, и это приводит к неоднозначности. Как быть в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Юзайте ParameterizedThreadStart или ThreadStart и читайте сообщения компилятора.

```
var thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(A));
var thread2 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(A));
thread1.Start();  // first
thread2.Start();  // second

public static void A()
{
    Console.WriteLine("first");
}

public static void A(object o)
{
    Console.WriteLine("second");
}
```

Comment: О, спасибо. Я не догадался явно указать, через какой делегат вызывать метод!!!